# Transformar uma string em várias substrings cujo conteúdo está entre apóstrofes

Tags: c#, .net, string

estou criando um programa em C# que lê um arquivo texto e uma das linhas desse arquivo tem o seguinte formato:

'Coluna 1' 'Coluna 2' 'Coluna 3'

Quero transformar essa linha em uma *array* de strings de modo que a resposta fique assim:

```
    Colunas[0] = "Coluna 1"
    Colunas[1] = "Coluna 2"
    Colunas[2] = "Coluna 3"
```

Ou seja, quero que ele identifique cada string dentro de apóstrofes e as guarde no array.
Tentei fazer isso lendo a linha toda usando o seguinte código:

```
    string Linha = Leitor.ReadLine(); //Leitor é o StreamReader que lê o arquivo
```

E depois tentei usar o método `linha.Split`

```
    var NomesColunas = linha.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Mas aí o resultado ficou o seguinte: {"Coluna", "1", "Coluna", "2", "Coluna", "3" }. Tentei usar o apóstrofe como `char` para fazer o Split mas tá dando erro de compilação, não estou acertando a sintaxe.

Comment: Como ficou o seu `Split`? Edita sua resposta e coloca lá, fica melhor do que nos comentários, eu acho.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica! Coloquei lá, acho que ficou mais bem explicado.

Comment: Que formato de arquivo mais inconveniente...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usando regex ficaria algo como:

```
'([^']+)'
```

Desta maneira ele pegará "ilimitados"

Um exemplo seria isto (não tenho muito entendimento de C#, qualquer falha pode criticar/corrigir):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string linha = "'Oi 1' 'tchau 2' 'hello 3' 'good bye 4'";
        string regex = @"'([^']+)'";
        MatchCollection match = Regex.Matches(linha, @regex);

        string[] dados = new string[match.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < dados.Length; i++)
        {
            dados[i] = match[i].Groups[1].Value;
            Console.WriteLine(dados[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Note que usei `string[]` ao invés de `List`, pois entendi que era assim que estava trabalhando, mas isto não muda em nada o entendimento, basta ajustar.

- Exemplo do regex: https://regex101.com/r/rFOe4D/2
- Exemplo de teste com C#: http://ideone.com/zO1f8O

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Não conhecia as regular expressions (sou novo na programação). Aproveitei pra dar uma estudada no assunto pra entender o código que você escreveu!

Answer (score 4):

Obviamente que se tem um apóstrofe para usar como `char` teria que escapá-lo para não confundir o compilador e misturar o que é delimitador do caractere e o caractere (`'\''`). Mas como tem mais de um caractere como padrão então tem que usar uma `string` e não um `char`.

Você tem que remover o apóstrofe inicial e final e depois separar ([`Split()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_String_Split_System_String___System_StringSplitOptions_)) pelo padrão que é "um apóstrofe, um espaço, um apóstrofe". Assim:

```
using static System.Console;
using System;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var texto = "'Coluna 1' 'Coluna 2' 'Coluna 3'";
        texto = texto.Substring(1, texto.Length - 2);
        var items = texto.Split(new string[] {"' '"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
        foreach (var item in items) WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/AadTWK). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/u4REtE). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Split3.cs).

Essa deve ser a forma mais simples. Tem como desenvolver um algoritmo mais elegante, mas não será tão simples.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado pela dica. Só que tem um porém...não necessariamente tem apenas um espaço entre as strings que eu quero ler, pode ter mais. Se eu for editar todos os arquivos de entrada pra deixar apenas um espaço entre os apóstrofes vou perder um tempão...

Comment: Isso não está na pergunta, eu só posso responder oque foi perguntado. Tem um limite? Pode preencher o *array* de padrões com as outras formas `"'  '"`, `"'   '"`, etc. Se puder ser muito aí precisa de uma outra solução. Uma delas seria tirar esses espaços antes, talvez com um `Replace()`, ou pode ser interessante fazer um método *lexer* próprio, mas não sei se compensa, porque para ter performance não seria tão simples fazer.

Comment: Realmente não mencionei isso nas perguntas, peço desculpas...limite não tem, eu quero ler a linha independentemente do número de espaços entre as expressões. A solução com regex funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 2):

A reposta acima tem o que você precisa, implementei aqui uma forma um pouco diferente.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string linha = "'Coluna 1' 'Coluna 2' 'Coluna 3'";

        linha = linha.Replace("' ",",").Replace("'","");

        string[] linhas = linha.Split(',');
        foreach(var item in linhas)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/W2XOu8

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Entretanto para um caso em que houver mais de um espaço entre as expressões o resultado não fica perfeito. Acabou que esqueci de mencionar isso na pergunta, peço desculpas por isso. A solução com regex funcionou do jeito que eu precisava.

Comment: O Regex realmente ajuda em muitas coisas assim, mas muitas vezes é um pouco mais lento. o importante e que você resolveu seu problema.